# return array in function

Tags: php, arrays

I want to translate each words in array:

```
$myarray = array("hi","bro");
```

So I wrote a translate function like this:

```
function translate($word) {    

    foreach ( $word as $key_translate ) {
        $array = array();

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `translate` WHERE name = '".$key_translate."'  ");
        if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1 ) {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
          $name = $row['fa_name'];
          return $name;
        //retuen array($name);
        }
        else {
          return $key_translate;
        //return array($key_translate);
        }
    }       
}
```

And using this to show translated array:

```
print_r (translate($myarray));
```

But it's not returning array, it's just showing first key as string.

How can I return array in function?

Comment: `return $name` and `return $key_translate` just returns that one element, why do you expect it to return an array?

Comment: Since you use `return` in the loop, you never process anything but the first element of the array.

Comment: @Barmar please see commented line

Comment: `mysql_query` is [deprecated](http://uk3.php.net/mysql_query) and should be avoided. You should use PDO or mysqli instead as these are much more secure.

Comment: @user3325376 That still just returns after you translate the first word. It returns it in an array, but it's only one word, not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return inside the loop, that exits the whole function immediately and just returns that one element. Accumulate the results in an array, and return that.

```
function translate($word) {

    $result = array();
    foreach ( $word as $key_translate ) {

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT fa_name FROM `translate` WHERE name = '".$key_translate."'  ");
        if ( mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1 ) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            $result[] = $row['fa_name'];
        }
        else {
            $result[] = $key_translate;

        }
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Also, there's no reason to use `SELECT *` if you're only interested in `fa_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function translate($word) {
    foreach ($word as $key => $translate) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `translate` WHERE name = '" . $translate . "'  ");
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            $word[$key] = $row['fa_name'];
        }
    }
    return $word;
}
```